# Alternate options for symbolic links (ln)

Tags: permissions, symlink, alias

I want to create an alias of my home folder but I don't have write permissions on parent directory.

I used to have a username (`user`) on an **old** server. But now, I'm using a **new** server and my username has been changed to `user2`. Many of my scripts have absolute path to my old home folder name (`/home/user`).  I want them to be compatible on my new server, in which my home folder now is different (`/home/user2`).

Obviously, I could've just created a **symbolic link** to my previous home name (`ln -s /home/user2 /home/user`). However, I don't have **write permissions** to the `/home` directory.

Is there any **alternate option** to create such alias without root permissions?

**Details:**

I'm using CentOS 5.

Comment: Ask your admin to create the symlink.

Answer (score 6):

If your scripts are using paths based on the location of your home directory, use tilde `~` or an environment variable such as `$HOME` instead of hardcoding the absolute path.

Comment: @rikoji use `awk` or `sed` to replace your hard coded path.